# Best way to collect logs from a remote server

Tags: unix, expect

I need to run some commands on some remote Solaris/Linux servers and collect their output in a log file on my local server.

Currently, I'm using a simple Expect script, residing on the local server to fire the commands on the target system. I then redirect the output of the expect script to a log file, like this,

```
/usr/local/bin/expect script.exp >> logfile.txt
```

However, this is proving to be very unreliable as the connection to the server fluctuates a lot, leading to incomplete logs and hung scripts.

Is there a better and more reliable way to go about this task?

Comment: I think it is better to create an script that performs all the commands. This script will print the output in a temporary file that then you can `scp` or `sftp` to your local server.

Comment: Yes this thought did cross my mind, but I have more than 80 or so remote servers and uploading to each one of them is going to be very tedious. Moreover, the commands need to be modified often. Hence this may not be feasible for me :/

Comment: Create a script to deploy the scripts. Define a directory in which you store these scripts and its output. With basic loops you can update scripts within few minutes. It is very clean and easy to maintain if you follow the same rules in all server.

Comment: Sure. If you need help on any part, feel free to start a new question. Success!

Comment: Thanks again, I successfully implemented this scheme and it works perfectly :) However, I would still like to learn about any alternate method to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented fedorqui's answer,

- Created a (shell) script that runs the required commands on the target servers.
- Deployed this script to all servers.
- Executed this script via expect, from my local (central) server.
- Finally collected logs individually from each server after successful completion, and processed them.

The solution has been working fine without a glitch till now.